# Loop back problem for Laptop

Tags: apache-flex, microphone, netstream

We are developing a video chatting application on flex, it works well on Desktop systems and while running on a laptop the sound is loop backed and becomming a large noise, Please help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to your problem from a coding from a coding standpoint.  But, from a sound standpoint, feedback is created when the microphone picks up the sound coming out of the speaker that is amplifying the sound.  So, kind of like this:

1. Speak into a Microphone
2. Your voice comes out of the speaker
3. The microphone picks uo your voice from the speaker
4. Your "speaker" voice is now coming out of the "speaker" a second time.
5. The microphone picks up the speaker noise, etc..

When setting up sound for live bands, it is best to get the microphone as far away from the monitors as possible.  Some people even suggest making sure the "vocal" mic is perpendicular to the speaker.

I envision that here is nothing, codewise, you can do to solve this problem, if this is in fact your problem.

Try a headset mic on the laptop.  Does that solve the problem?